# AWK: Delete All Lines When Columns 1 & 2 Match

Tags: awk

I'd like to not just delete the duplicates, but also the line being check when a duplicate occurs.

**Existing Code**

```
awk '!a[$1$2]++'
```

**Input**

```
HNSONV  LSVRNV  10  srlg-value  52000
HNSONV  PHNAAZ  0   srlg-value  53000
HRHNLA  PNSCFL  0   srlg-value  54000
HRHNLA  PNSCFL  10  srlg-value  55000
HRHNLA  PNSCFL  20  srlg-value  54500
HRHNLA  PNSCFL  30  srlg-value  55500
JHSNAR  KSCYMO  0   srlg-value  56000
JHSNAR  OKCYOK  0   srlg-value  57000
```

**Output**

```
HNSONV  LSVRNV  10  srlg-value  52000
HNSONV  PHNAAZ  0   srlg-value  53000
JHSNAR  KSCYMO  0   srlg-value  56000
JHSNAR  OKCYOK  0   srlg-value  57000
```

Answer (score 1):

a two pass algorithm

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]++; next} a[$1,$2]==1' file{,}

HNSONV  LSVRNV  10  srlg-value  52000
HNSONV  PHNAAZ  0   srlg-value  53000
JHSNAR  KSCYMO  0   srlg-value  56000
JHSNAR  OKCYOK  0   srlg-value  57000
```

note the `,` in the array keys to prevent false positive matches due to concatenation of two strings (e.g. "AB A" and "A BA" will end up the same key in your version).

Answer (score 0):

assuming first two fields are always of `14` in character length and duplicates are all next to each other like the given sample (sort the input if needed):

```
$ uniq -w14 -u ip.txt
HNSONV  LSVRNV  10  srlg-value  52000
HNSONV  PHNAAZ  0   srlg-value  53000
JHSNAR  KSCYMO  0   srlg-value  56000
JHSNAR  OKCYOK  0   srlg-value  57000
```

From `man uniq`

> uniq - report or omit repeated lines
>
> -u, --unique
>   only print unique lines
>
> -w, --check-chars=N
>   compare no more than N characters in lines