# Using AWK to preserve lines based on a single line field being repeated/duplicate in a CSV file

Tags: bash, awk

Would someone help me form a script in Bash to keep only the unique lines, based solely on identifying duplicate values in a single field (the first field)

If I have data like this:

```
123456,23423,Smith,John,Jacob,Main  St.,,Houston,78003<br>
654321,54524,Smith,Jenny,,Main  St.,,Houston,78003<br>
332423,9023432,Gonzales,Michael,,Everyman,,Dallas,73423<br>
123456,324324,Bryant,Kobe,,Special St.,,New York,2311<br>
234324,232411,Willis,Bruce,,Sunset Blvd,,Hollywood,90210<br>
438329,34233,Moore,Mike,,Whatever,,Detroit,92343<br>
654321,43234,Smith,Jimbo,,Main  St.,,Houston,78003<br>
```

And I like to only keep the lines which do not have matching first fields
(result would be a file with these contents below, based on above sample)

```
332423,9023432,Gonzales,Michael,,Everyman,,Dallas,73423<br>
234324,232411,Willis,Bruce,,Sunset Blvd,,Hollywood,90210<br>
438329,34233,Moore,Mike,,Whatever,,Detroit,92343<br>
```

What would the bash/awk approach be?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It'd be 2 passes - the first to count the occurrences of each key field, the second to print the lines whose key field was only counted as appearing once in the first pass. The correct way to do it is using `awk`. Try it and post your attempt if you need help. See [ask].

Comment: not exact duplicate, but close enough -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50395656/awk-delete-all-lines-when-columns-1-2-match ..

Comment: Easy way is `sort | uniq -w7 -u` (assuming GNU tools, and a consistent first field width).